# show image stored outside the public folder in view file - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have images in storage/app/uploads/image.jpg, I run command 
`Php artisan storage:link` After that in my view file I used this:

```
img src={{ asset('storage/app/upload/image.jpg') }}
```

but the image is not showing. I don't want to put my images in public folder. Any help would be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You said that you have images on `uploads` folder but then your src says `upload/`.
2. You need to create a route where you can fetch the images.

   ```
    Route::get('images/{filename}', function ($filename)
   {
    $path = app_path('upload') . '/' . $filename;

    $file = File::get($path);
    $type = File::mimeType($path);

    $response = Response::make($file, 200);
    $response->header("Content-Type", $type);

    return $response;
    })->name('route.name');
   ```

Then in your blade file, all you have to do is call the route and the file name of the image separated by a comma.

```
img src={{ route('route.name', 'image.jpg') }}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to store your files inside `storage/app/public` (which is what the `storage:link` symlink does), then you need to create a route:

```
Route::get('show-image', function() {
   $file = storage_path('app/upload/image.jpg');

   return response()->file($file);
})
```

Comment: what will be the img src in that case ??

Comment: In this pseudo example, yes `<img src="/show-image">`